# has_many through create relationship from existing models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through, nested-resources

I have a marketplace where my users can create plans and their customers can join them. So I have a Plan model and a Customer model. The end goal is to subscribe a customer to a plan so I created a Subscription model and a has_many :through association but I need some help on getting the create working properly. A plan and a customer are already existing by the time the subscription is able to happen so I don't need to worry about creating the plan or customer on subscription#create, I just need to worry about joining the existing ones.

Where I'm at right now is I got the create working on the subscriptions model, but it's not associating to the correct customer. I need a Subscription model created for every customer that I subscribe to the plan and I'm using a multi select tag.

I'm using a has_many :through because a plan has many customers but a customer can also have many plans.

Please let me know if anything is not clear I tried to explain it as clearly and concisely as possible.

Plan Model

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subscriptions
    has_many :customers, through: :subscriptions
end
```

Customer Model

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subscriptions
    has_many :plans, through: :subscriptions, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

Subscription Model

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :plan
    belongs_to :customer
end
```

Routes.rb

```
  resources :customers
  resources :plans do
    resources :subscriptions
  end
```

Subscriptions Controller

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @user = current_user
        @company = @user.company
        @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
        @subscription = Subscription.new
    end

    def create
        if @subscription = Subscription.create(plan_id: params[:subscription][:plan_id] )
            @subscription.customer_id = params[:subscription][:customer_id]
            @subscription.save
            flash[:success] = "Successfully Added Customers to Plan"
            redirect_to plan_path(params[:subscription][:plan_id])
        else
            flash[:danger] = "There was a problem adding your customers to this plan"
            render :new
        end
    end
    private

    def subscription_params
        params.require(:subscription).permit(:customer_id, :plan_id, :stripe_subscription_id)
    end
end
```

Form:

```
    <%= form_for [@plan, @subscription] do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :plan_id, value: @plan.id %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <%= f.select :customer_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@company.customers, 'id', 'customer_name', @plan.customers), {}, multiple: true, style: "width: 50%;" %><br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <%= f.submit "Add Customer To Plan", class: "btn btn-success pull-right" %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"###",
 "subscription"=>{"plan_id"=>"5", "customer_id"=>["", "153", "155"]},
 "commit"=>"Add Customer To Plan",
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"subscriptions",
 "plan_id"=>"5"}
```

Comment: You can replace this `@subscription = Subscription.create(plan_id: params[:subscription][:plan_id] )` with  `@subscription = Subscription.create(params[:subscription])`

Comment: @MaxWilliams When I tried that I got a strong params error saying forbidden attiributes. When I do `Subscription.create(subscription_params)` I have the same issue where it's not associated with the customer.

Answer (score 0):

params[:subscription][:customer_id] is an array:

```
 "subscription"=>{"plan_id"=>"5", "customer_id"=>["", "153", "155"]},
```

Are you actually trying to set up a subscription between the plan and each of the customers in this array?  If so try calling the update method for `@plan` object instead, passing these through in `params[:plan][:customer_ids]` (note the s)

EDIT:

When i said "pass through the ids in `params[:plan][:customer_ids]`" i was expecting you to do the standard controller behaviour for update, which is something along the lines of

```
@plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
@plan.update_attributes(params[:plan])
```

if `params = {:plan => {:customer_ids => [1,2,3]}}` then the above code will be doing this:

```
@plan.update_attributes({:customer_ids => [1,2,3]})
```

which is like saying

```
@plan.customer_ids = [1,2,3]
@plan.save
```

When you set up an association, you get lots of methods you can call on the object.  One of them is `<association>_ids`, in this case `customer_ids`, which is a way of setting the association:  when you save, it will make the association between @plan and customers 1,2 & 3.

You were doing this:

```
@plan.customers << params[:plan][:customer_ids]
```

which is mixing up the customer records with the ids.  If you're going to use `push`, aka `<<`, you need to push in customer objects, not ids.  Just using `customer_ids =` is a quicker and simpler way of doing this.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I tried changing it to the plan update action by doing `@plan.customers << params[:plan][:customer_ids]` and then `@plan.save` but I keep getting "ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch" errors so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.